# Why cannot my Ionic 3 app communicate with the internet even with a valid IP address?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am using Ionic 3 with Cordova 8 to run a simple application on both Android and iOS. When the user presses a button, some collected data is sent to an external server -- however, upon inspection, the app is unable to send the data for some reason. I've read all the relevant documentation and forum posts that relate to this and I'm without an explanation.

EDIT: This also occurs on a fresh Ionic 4 app with Cordova 9.

I've check my config.xml for unusual settings / permissions, but everything appears sensible - in particular, it contains the following lines:

```
<access origin="*" />
<allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
```

My app successfully reads the valid IP of the phone it's operating on the network. What would cause an Ionic 3 app to obtain a valid network IP (or use the underlying platform's) but not communicate with the outside world?

ADB log : https://gist.github.com/JesseRMeyer/9f93b07fb8dcf56e2907178f35d70ff8

Comment: Do you have a concrete error message? Any errors in the javascript console?

Comment: @Phonolog Nope. The runtime does not seem aware of any problems.

Comment: "upon inspection, the app is unable to send the data for some reason." How exactly did you come to this conclusion? Without any errors, warnings, or notices - or access to your app itself it will be pretty hard to help you here.

Comment: @NickyTheWrench I'm preparing more evidence shortly (by manually POSTing some information and showing the aftermath). Stay tuned.

Comment: @JesseMeyer Excellent - let us know the results :-)

Comment: @NickyTheWrench Ok, so after generating POST messages directly, the app can, in fact, communicate successfully with an outside network. It appears that the networking functionality from another plugin that I'm trying to use is functioning incorrectly and led me down this wild goose chase. Thanks for for interest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The application can communicate on the internet fine. A plugin I am using, however, was improperly configured to communicate on the network.

Answer (score 0):

You should allow Cross Origin request at receiving server as well, If it is a post call then reciever might not accept it because of the fact it is coming from some unknown origin.

To work through it, Allow receiver to accept cross origin request.

Example -

In Java REST API's we use annotation as given below :

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
```

You can check for your code , or share it here.

Comment: can you debug your app via chrome devices and paste logs here.

Comment: The ADB log is : https://gist.github.com/JesseRMeyer/9f93b07fb8dcf56e2907178f35d70ff8

Overall, nothing very suggestive is present.

The two lines that stand out to me are:
...CordovaPlugin: Attempted to send a second callback for ID: networkinterface32471367
    Result was: "Invalid action"
...CordovaPlugin: Attempted to send a second callback for ID: networkinterface32471368
    Result was: "Invalid action"